# Как сделать несколько модальных окон на странице jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Всем привет, подскажите как сделать единую функцию для открытия нескольких модальных окон?

У меня есть такое модальное окно

```
<div id="import" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title">Модальное окно</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                    Окно
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-cancel" data-dismiss="modal">Отмена</button>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

И есть JS код который его открывает с использованием jQuery

```
$('.importcsv').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    linkforemove = $(this).attr('href');
    $('#import').modal();
})
```

И кнопка при клике на котрую все происходит

```
<a href="" class="btn btn-warning importcsv">
 Импортировать спонсоров из csv
</a>
```

Но если у меня много таких окон то мне придется постоянно копировать js код что бы они работали? как мне сделать так что бы окон было много а js остался один? id="import" можно нумеровать id="import-1" id="import-2" а что с JS делать?

Comment: а linkforemove = $(this).attr('href'); - это у Вас для чего?

Answer (score 1):

**UPD:**
А вообще, раз уж Вы используете bootstrap + jquery, Вам дополнительный js-код для открытия модальных окон и вовсе не нужен (всё <s>украдено</s> написано до нас) - просто добавьте ссылкам атрибут data-toggle="modal":

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css"> 
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 

<div id="import" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title">Модальное окно 1</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                    Окно
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-cancel" data-dismiss="modal">Отмена</button>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<a href="#import" class="btn btn-warning importcsv" data-toggle="modal">
 Импортировать спонсоров из csv 1
</a>

<div id="import-1" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title">Модальное окно 2</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                    Окно
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-cancel" data-dismiss="modal">Отмена</button>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<a href="#import-1" class="btn btn-warning importcsv" data-toggle="modal">
 Импортировать спонсоров из csv 2
</a>
```

---

---

Вы вот не отвечаете на мой вопрос, зачем Вам в коде linkforemove = $(this).attr('href'); а между тем в этой переменной вся соль - в неё записывается href ссылки, чтобы увязать ссылку с модальным окном:

```js
$('.importcsv').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var linkforemove = $(this).attr('href');
    $(linkforemove).modal();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css"> 
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 

<div id="import" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title">Модальное окно 1</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                    Окно
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-cancel" data-dismiss="modal">Отмена</button>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<a href="#import" class="btn btn-warning importcsv">
 Импортировать спонсоров из csv 1
</a>

<div id="import-1" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title">Модальное окно 2</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                    Окно
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-cancel" data-dismiss="modal">Отмена</button>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<a href="#import-1" class="btn btn-warning importcsv">
 Импортировать спонсоров из csv 2
</a>
```